# Unable to select or type in dropdown textbox

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to select or sendkeys on a dropdown textbox. Tried explicit and implicit wait and Thread.sleep(), sometimes the element is not interactable or no such element.

Tried select dropdown but an error occurs (not select it was div or a), click then sendkeys, press up and press enter.

Code

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='btnsave']")));    
        WebElement save = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='btnsave']"));
        save.click();
```

HTML

```
<tbody xpath="1"><tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkIsDateFilter" checked="checked"></td>
                            <td>Date From 从:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="txtDateFrom" class="hasDatepicker"></td>
                            <td>Date To 至:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="txtDateTo" class="hasDatepicker"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>Location 地点:</td>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <select id="ddllocation" class="max chzn-done" style="display: none;">
                                    <option value="0">ALL 全部</option><option value="10" selected="selected">10</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option>                             </select><div id="ddllocation_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 392px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1" style=""><span style="">ALL 全部</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 390.021px; top: 23px;"><div class="chzn-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 355.042px;"></div><ul class="chzn-results"><li id="ddllocation_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected" style="">ALL 全部</li><li id="ddllocation_chzn_o_1" class="active-result" style="">10</li><li id="ddllocation_chzn_o_2" class="active-result" style="">15</li><li id="ddllocation_chzn_o_3" class="active-result" style="">16</li></ul></div></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>Bank Acct. 银行账号: </td>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <select id="ddlbank" class="max">
                                    <option value="0" selected="selected">ALL 全部</option>                               </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>Status 状态:  </td>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <select id="ddlStatus" class="max" style="">
                                    <option value="0">ALL 全部</option>
                                    <option value="1">Payable 未过账</option>
                                    <option value="3">Transferred 已过帐</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>Filter by 过滤:</td>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <select id="ddlDateFilterType" class="max">
                                    <option value="0">Date Issued 支付日期</option>
                                    <option value="1">Check Date 支票日期</option>
                                    <option value="2">ALL 全部</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>Order By 排列:</td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <select id="ddlorder" class="max">
                                    <option value="issueddate">Issued Date 支付日期</option>
                                    <option value="checkdate">Check Date 支票日期</option>
                                    <option value="fullname">Pay To 付给</option>
                                    <option value="checkno">Check No. 支票号</option>
                                    <option value="accountname">Bank 银行</option>
                                    <option value="amount">Amount 总价</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><input id="btnToggle" type="button" value="ASC" class="bttn-sort"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Should select properly

Comment: perhaps you forgot to include some code in your question above?  I don't see any selenium code to select an item seen in the HTML you provided.  Nor do I see a "btnsave" element that your selenium code is trying to click on in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You have not used the dropdown Select class for selecting Dropdown value.
For dropdown in selenium we are using **Select class** for selecting dropdown value.
Below are the code:

```
Webelemnt Dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='ddlStatus']"));
Select SelectDropdown= new Select(Dropdown);
SelectDropdown.selectByValue("0"); OR SelectDropdown.selectByVisibleText("Date Issued 支付日期");
```